# Uploading mirror Java Quickstart to App Engine

Tags: google-mirror-api

Question about getting the Java starter project booted up on Google App Engine

https://developers.google.com/glass/quickstart/java

In that quickstart when configuring Eclipse it says

> Uncheck the Use Google App Engine checkbox and save.

However if I follow the instructions on the above page - including Eclipse with the Google plugin - I get a project which can be run on localhost. If I try to upload the App Engine it says *this is not a App Engine project* and won't upload.

So then if I make it one (go under the Google->App Engine settings) the Eclipse project complains about the jars under

> web/WEB-INF/lib

and still won't upload. If I delete them then I get a project that doesn't compile either. So what do I need to do specifically to get this to load to the cloud?

Related to this is that I'm confused about the relationship between Maven and Eclipse - the two seem to be a cross purposes as Maven populates the lib directory but I keep wrangling with Eclipse over it too. The App Engine plugin seems to want to use it's jars, while the app-engine code I downloaded per the instructions (to get the bin utils app-cfg) want to be used too by Maven AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

Deploy to App Engine from the command line using `appcfg.sh`.

Getting many IDEs and App Engine to all work in the same project has led to some compromises due to differing assumptions made by each of the tools involved. For example, the Eclipse App Engine plugin makes different assumptions about the structure of projects than other IDEs. The compromise was to fall back to the official command line tools since they seem the most tolerant of variation and are always available.

Maven is part of the project to handle dependency management.

If you'd like to use Eclipse for your deployment too, you'll probably want to create a new Eclipse App Engine project and copy the libraries and code into that project.